# Language C strtok has some error

Tags: c, strtok

I have a problem with my code, I keep on getting the compiler error:

> error message : 
>   **warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast**

My code is simple:

```
int i;
int arr1[8], arr2[8];
char test[] = "1|a|b;2|c|d;3|e|f";
char *split1, *split2;

split1 = strtok(test, ";");
for(i = 1; i <= 8; i++){
  arr1[i] = split1;
  split1 = strtok(NULL, ";");
  printf("result=%s\n", arr1[i]);
}
```

When I fix the compiler error, my code can't print value and vice versa!

Comment: `arr[8]` does not exist; you do not use `arr[0]`

Comment: change arr1 to a char*

Comment: Why are you putting pointers to strings into an array of integers?

Comment: Which line is the error on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides the error mention in your question, you also have lots of other errors. For example:

```
arr1[i]=split1;
```

The variable `split1` is a *string*, a pointer to `char`, while `arr1` is an array of `int`.

To convert a string containing a number to an integer, you can use [`strtol`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol).

If that's not what you want, you need to make `arr1` an array of strings, i.e. an array of pointer to `char`:

```
char *arr1[8];
```

---

You also have a more serious error once you get the program to compile: Array indexes are *zero based*. That means that array indexes go from zero to the size minus one, or in the case of `arr1` the indexes are from `0` to `7` (inclusive). Indexing an array out of bounds leads to [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Another case of undefined behavior is this line

```
printf("result=%s\n",arr1[i]);
```

Here you want to print a string, but provide an integer. This is not applicable if you change `arr1` to an array of strings, of course.

Comment: That line is making an integer from a pointer. The error message says pointer from integer.

Comment: Why would he use `strtol` in this code? His input data is not numeric. The first token is `1|a|b`.

Answer (score 3):

> error message : **warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast**

You need to include the proper prototype for the compiler to know what types the function returns (or it will assume they return `int`).

The prototype for `strtok()` is in `<string.h>`.

```
#include <string.h>

    split1=strtok(NULL,";"); // without a prototype
                             // the compiler assumes strtok() returns an int
                             // and complains about assigning the int to a pointer
```

Answer (score 0):

Well compiler warns you that it is wrong to assign pointer to an int value. First because pointer can be greater size then int.
In your case - you need to assign not a pointer but value referenced by it ( so just use arr1[i] = *split1;

But first check if split1 is not NULL, if you dereference NULL value you'll get access violation and you app will crash.

Btw, I recommend you to pay attention on previous answers, as they contain a lot of useful information for You.